# Optional ManyToOne relationship in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm building an application for SNMP Trap logging. It has two MySQL tables: one with the traps, and one with the hosts that I want to log.

The traps table is filled externally. The hosts can be entered through the website. A host CAN have one or many traps. A trap CAN have one host.

So this is a many to one relationship, but optional on both sides. How do I implement this, since Doctrine requires for one of the members to be a primary key, and therefore not nullable?

Code for both classes:

```php
class Trap
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="eventname", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $eventname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="eventid", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $eventid;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="trapoid", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $trapoid;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="enterprise", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $enterprise;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="community", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $community;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hostname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $hostname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="agentip", type="string", length=16)
     */
    private $agentip;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="severity", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $severity;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="uptime", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $uptime;

    /**
     * @var datetime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="traptime", type="datetime")
     */
    private $traptime;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="formatline", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $formatline;    

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Host", inversedBy="traps")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="agentip", referencedColumnName="ip", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $host;
}
```

```php
class Host
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="ip", type="string", length=16)
     */
    private $ip;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="hostname", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $hostname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="importance", type="integer", length=1)
     */
    private $importance;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Trap", mappedBy="host")
     */
    protected $traps;
}
```

**Edited with error**
The error is that I'm not allowed to delete or truncate my hosts table, which should be possible in my application, because traps must be able to exist without a host.

```
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`snmptt`.`snmptt`, CONSTRAINT `FK_9BF059B998B5BE9E` FOREIGN KEY (`agentip`) REFERENCES `hosts` (`ip`))
```

Comment: Your many to one relationship looks OK to me what error are you presented with?

Comment: The error is that I'm not allowed to delete or truncate my hosts table, which should be possible in my application, because traps must be able to exist without a host.

Comment: If you are trying to remove this as straight sequel then yes the error is correct you cannot remove the parent before unlink the child, if there is no parent then this is fine if so unlink first then remove

Comment: I've added the exact error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted as answer from comment as believe to be appropriate answer;

"If you are trying to remove this as straight sequel then yes the error is correct you cannot remove the parent before unlink the child, if there is no parent then this is fine if so unlink first then remove"

Comment: Can I do this without clearing the 'agentip' field in the 'trap' record?

Comment: Unfortunalty no, this a foriegn key constraint on the field host if the relationship does exist. Are you doing this via mysql or using doctrine? If you remove the Host do you want the trap to still exist?

Comment: Traps and Hosts need to exist without needing each other. There could be hosts with no traps (yet), or traps that are not linked to a host. Later, these 'orphaned' traps will be displayed in a different area of the website, but the program receiving the traps on the server has no way of identifying whether the trap has a host or not, so it puts them in the same table in the database.

Comment: So my answer is correct then, please mark as appropriate, next give me a minute or two to think of a solution

Comment: OK without changing your database design, knowing the reason for the business logic and without knowing how your programatically removing these the simple solution would be to unlink i.e. update child record based on if it has an associated parent link setting that column relationship to null then purge the parent record

Comment: I think I'm not fully understanding your comment. Could you provide an example for how to remove that link in MySQL?

Comment: Sure, UPDATE child SET column = null WHERE column = {$id}; DELETE FROM parent WHERE id = {$id};

Comment: Well yeah, but that column can not be NULL, because the information in that column is critical to the application... That also causes the problem when there are traps with no host. The field containing the FK is filled, but the other end not.

Comment: OK i'm completely confused as you just mentioned "Traps and Hosts need to exist without needing each other" such as nullable relationships now they are important, I'm going to move this into a discussion chat to prevent future form posting, to see if I can help you further or abandon

Comment: OK i cannot do this due to you stackoverflow level, please post complete business logic requirements for the application

Comment: Application receives traps from SNMPTT program. These traps have a fixed format, I can only specify in which database/table they need to be put.

Web application shows these traps and offer functionality to save info about hosts, e.g. : ip-address x.x.x.x is a Catalyst 2950 Switch. 

The app then combines this info to show that trap X belongs to host Y and thus is so ans so important.

I need to be able to have:
A) Traps with no related host
B) Hosts with no related traps

Comment: Traps with no related hosts will be shown in a separate area of the website. A PHP script splits the known traps from the unknown traps by means of a foreach loop that checks whether the agentip field of the trap table has a relationship in the host table